# How to get the email ID which i configured in mail client in android?

Tags: android, email, email-client

I have one page where user can see the mail.in that i am providing menu options as "Reply","ReplyAll".when user click on Reply/ReplyAll ,i am launching the chooser dialog(where user can choose which inbuilt app he can use while giving reply.now when he choose any app ,now i want to get the email id which i have configured in that app.

How can we get?any idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; 
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
        String possibleEmail = account.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case it is returning Gmail account.but i want the mail Id account which is choosen by user from the dialog